# DbContext issue with connection string login

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis

My `DbContext` has the following implementation

```
public class BusinessDataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public BusinessDataContext() : base(ConnectionStringManager.GetConnectionString())
    {
    }
}
```

`ConnectionStringManager` returns a connection string based on which machine I'm working from, since there are several, however as an example...

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BusinessDb;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$word123!;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

When I debug this from Visual Studio I don't run into any issues, however when I run under IIS, I get the following error

> Cannot open database "BusinessDb" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\BusinessDb'.

I don't understand why it's trying to log in as `IIS APPPOOL` when I've specified '`sa`' in the connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify SQL server authentication instead of Windows authentication by setting

```
 Integrated Security=false
```

in the connection string.

By setting `Integrated Security=true` the API tries to use Windows authentication and to log in `IIS APPPOOL\BusinessDb` which probably has no rights on your SQL server.